# Exception and Reflection

Tags: c#, exception, reflection

The web service has SoapExtension, which contains an error handler and serializing error in a format xml.

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" standalone = "yes"?>
<Exception Type="System.NullReferenceException"> Exception text. </ Exception>
```

How to make error handler, which call error of "Type"? E.g.:

```
Type _type = Type.GetType(doc.DocumentElement.Attributes["Type"].Value);
```

It must to call NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the fully-qualified name, i.e. "System.NullReferenceException".

In this particular case, that's enough - because `NullReferenceException` is in mscorlib. However, if you need other exceptions - such as [`ConstraintException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.constraintexception.aspx), which lives in the System.Data assembly - you'd need to provide the full assembly name too. `Type.GetType(string)` only looks in the currently executing assembly and mscorlib for type names which don't specify the assembly.

EDIT: Here's a short but complete program which works:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string typeName = "System.NullReferenceException";
        string message = "This is a message";
        Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
        object exception = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { message });
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK I correct xml: 
<Exception Type="System.NullReferenceException">Exception message.</Exception> 
How to call it?

Comment: @Dublicator: Well now you can use Type.GetType as per your existing code. You'll then probably want to find a constructor taking a string parameter (use `Type.GetConstructor`) and invoke it.

Comment: I use such code:
ConstructorInfo ctor = _type.GetConstructor(new[] {typeof (string)});
object instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { _message });
But it's not work.

Comment: @Dublicator: "It's not work" isn't exactly a detailed description of the problem. Please edit your question with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. I'll do the same in my answer with a short but complete program which *does* work.

Comment: Thanks for help. See comment below. I forgot about parameter innerException.

Comment: @Dublicator: But you don't *have* an inner exception, do you?

Answer (score -1):

I use such code:

```
public static Exception Invoke(string soapMessage) {
    //...            
    string _message = doc.DocumentElement.InnerText;
    Type_type = Type.GetType(doc.DocumentElement.Attributes["Type"].Value);
    ConstructorInfo constructor = _type.GetConstructor(new[] {typeof (string), _type.GetType()});
    try {
        Exception ctor = (Exception)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { _message, _type });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look right to me - why are you passing in the type as an extra constructor argument? And why are you *returning* an exception *thrown* by invoking the constructor? See my answer for a *real* working answer. The reason this *appears* to work is that you're actually *causing* a NullReferenceException by asking for a constructor which doesn't exist, and then calling Invoke on that null reference. It won't work for other exception types.