# Grab the last exception using reflection or through HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError()

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, reflection

I have a method that is called when an exception is thrown. Only the `Exception.ToString()` is passed to it. It is not possible at this time to change the parameters to accept an `Exception` instead of a string, because we would have to change a lot of pages and I have no control over that (please I don't need anyone telling me to do that, because trust me I would love to just do that). We already have a class that handles the exceptions, but I have the opportunity to update this method and I wanted to know if it was possible to grab the last exception using reflection or using `HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError()`. With the `GetLastError()` it does not work because the exception was handled. Is there a way around this maybe with reflection or something? Any help is greatly appreciated. If this was discussed before, please show me because I was unable to find a similar question.

Comment: Can you store the last exception before it clears in session?  There is no way to get the last error without using GetLastError().

Comment: Sadly no. The other solution I've thought of was to recreate it using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810111/exception-and-reflection with the toString() details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fast solution I used for now (using some info from [Exception and Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810111/exception-and-reflection)):

```
 string typeName = err.Substring(0, err.IndexOf(":"));
 string message = err.Length > typeName.Length + 2 ? err.Substring(err.IndexOf(":") + 1) : string.Empty;
 Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
 ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
 object exception = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { message });
```

string err is the Exception.ToString(), which will have the type of exception and then I make the message the rest of the tostring method. This will do actually. If I wanted to be really explicit I could have used reflection to edit each property, but there is room for error there and the tostring actually will have everything and since I am creating the exception type it's all good in the hood. :) Hope this helps someone